# Jquery or Javascript mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, javascript-framework, frontend

i build hr, accounts and other management system with laravel at backend. Ajax is used in many pages for pagination, crud operations and for other purposes but website is not completely based on ajax. does backbone or other javascript mvc is suitable to manage front-end or jquery alone can handle this

i want to explorer backbone and other front-end frameworks but wonders that it increase complexity at frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally backbone is used for highly ajaxified websites. So if you are not using ajax to that limit, according to me jQuery itself is capable to handle it.

Comment: jquery is light-weight, efficent and easy to learn an apply but i feel it doesnot help me to write well managed code

Comment: If you want to write well managed code, definitely MVC structure is a better option and for that use of backbone is highly appreciated.

Comment: does frontend MVC help me to write managed code without increasing  much complexity at frontend? also capable of handle multiples pages b/c this is not an single page app.

Comment: yes it is not that complex. I have also worked on it. Infact you will find your code much cleaner after using this. It works on multiple pages but in case of multiple pages its main style of working i.e. "using hash" will be of no use

Comment: As a new backbone user I highly recommend you checkout one of the many backbone.js frameworks.  

- http://marionettejs.com/
- https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin
- https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki

Comment: Thanks Scott Puleo it's really helpful for me. i will see it tonight

Answer (score 0):

well backbone.js is exactly what you want some other popular options include angularjs as well as knockout.js. Each has its place and they all do slightly different things. If you are focusing CRUD type operations AnuglarJS is a very good choice. knockout.js helps make very rich user experiences easily and maintain-ably. Backbone.js is more of a cleaner jQuery in my opinion with some easier to understand syntax.

I would take a look at doing a simple example in each and then pick one from that. the choice is highly dependent on style and personal preference.

Comment: does front-end MVC is for those websites where logic are heavily depend on backend frameworks ?

Comment: not necessarily you can have the logic anywhere it tends to be a mix of client and server side. Mainly utilizing AJAX to call the server methods.